# Why do the outliers appear at whisker when I add them via geom_jitter with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have the following boxplots:

[image: boxplots]

As you can see, at the fourth boxplot, the outliers appear already at 4 on the y-axis. The whisker goes until 6.

I couldn't really figure out where the problem in my code is. The intention to show the outlier with `geom_jitter` is because the plot does not give enough information on the actual distribution.

Here is my code and below an excerpt from the data to try

```
my_xlab <- paste(levels(df$income_class),"\n(N=",table(df$income_class),")",sep="")
df %>% 
  group_by(income_class) %>% 
  mutate(outlier = nr_trips > median(nr_trips) + IQR(nr_trips) * 1.5) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=income_class, y=nr_trips)) + 
  geom_boxplot(varwidth = TRUE, outlier.shape = NA)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=my_xlab)+
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", 
               aes(shape="mean"), 
               size=4,
               colour = "red",
               geom="point") +
  scale_shape_manual("", values=c("mean"="x"))+
  theme_minimal() + 
  geom_jitter(data = function(x) dplyr::filter_(x, ~ outlier), width = 0.25, height = 0, alpha = .1, aes(color = "outlier")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("outlier" = "black"))+
  labs(x = "Income class", y="Number of AToD trips")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,2,4,6,8, 10, 12, 14), limits = c(0, 12))
```

The data:

```
structure(list(income_class = c("1", "1", "1", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "2", "3", "2", "4", "1", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "2", "3", 
"1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "2", "3", "2", "2", "3", 
"3", "3", "4", "4", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "3", "3", "2", "2", 
"3", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", "1", 
"2", "2", "2", "3", "4", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "2", 
"3", "3", "1", "1", "4", "4", "2", "2", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "1", "1", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "3", "4", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", 
"2", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", 
"4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "2", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "4", "2", "2", "3", "2", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "2", "2", "2", 
"3", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "3", "1", "3", "3", "2", "2", 
"2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", 
"4", "4", "2", "3", "3", "1", "2", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "3", 
"3", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "1", "4", "4", "4", "1", "1", "3", 
"4", "4", "1", "3", "1", "2", "2", "2", "4", "1", "2", "1", "2", 
"3", "2", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "1", "3", "3", "4", "4", "2", 
"2", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", 
"2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"2", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", 
"4", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "3", "4", "4", "4", "2", 
"2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "1", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "4", "3", "1", "1", "1", "4", "2", 
"2", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "4", "3", "4", "4", "2", "3", "3", 
"3", "1", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "4", 
"3", "2", "2", "2", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "1", "2", 
"1", "4", "4", "4", "1", "1", "4", "3", "3", "4", "4", "1", "1", 
"4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "2", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1", "3", "3", "4", "1", 
"2", "3", "2", "4", "2", "2", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", 
"2", "2", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "3", "2", "2", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "4", "4", "2", "4", "4", "1", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "2", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "1", "3", "3", "3", "1", "4", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"3", "4", "4", "3", "3", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "4", "4", "4", 
"1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "1", "1", 
"2", "1", "4", "4", "1", "4", "4", "3", "2", "2", "4", "2", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "2", "3", 
"4", "2", "4", "4", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "4", "2", "2", 
"2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "3", 
"3", "1", "3", "3", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "4", "4", "1", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", 
"2", "4", "4", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "1", "3", "3", 
"1", "1", "4", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", 
"3", "4", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "2", "3", 
"3", "2", "3", "3", "1", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", 
"3", "4", "4", "3", "3", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "1", "1", "2", "4", "4", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "1", "3", 
"3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "4", "3", "3", "3", "4", "3", 
"1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "3", 
"2", "1", "3", "2", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "3", "3", 
"3", "2", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", 
"4", "1", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", 
"4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "4", "3", "3", "3", "2", "4", "4", "1", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "4", 
"4", "3", "4", "3", "2", "2", "3", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "4", "4", "2", "3", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "3", "2", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "2", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "2", 
"2", "2", "4", "4", "2", "3", "3", "2", "4", "2", "4", "2", "3", 
"3", "2", "3", "3", "4", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "4", "4", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "2", "3", 
"3", "2", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "4", "2", "2", "3", "4", "3", 
"3", "3", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "3", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "2", "2", 
"4", "4", "4", "3", "4", "4", "3", "2", "2", "2", "3", "4", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "1", "2", "4", "2", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "2", 
"2", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "2", "2", "3", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"1", "2", "1", "1", "4", "2", "2", "4", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "4", "2", "2", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "2", 
"2", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "1", "1", 
"1", "3", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "4", "4", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "1", "4", "4", "2", "3", "2", "3", "4", "2", "2", "1", 
"1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "3", "3", "1", "3", "3", "4", "4", 
"2", "3", "3", "1", "4", "2", "2", "3", "2", "1", "3", "3", "1", 
"2", "2", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "2", "4", 
"2", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", "3", "1", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"1", "3", "3", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "4", 
"3", "3", "1", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "1", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "1", "4", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "3", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "4", "4", "4", "2", "3", "3", "3", "1", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", 
"2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "1", "1", "2", 
"2", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "2", "1", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "1", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "1", "1", "4", "2", "3", "3", "2", 
"3", "3", "1", "4", "4", "4", "4", "1", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", 
"2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "1", "3", "3", "2", "1", "4", "1", "2", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "4", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", 
"1", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "4", "1", "1", "3", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", 
"3", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", 
"2", "3", "3", "4", "3", "2", "2", "4", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"1", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "1", "4", "3", "2", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", 
"1", "2", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "4", "3", "1", 
"3", "3", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "2", "2", "3", "3", "2", 
"3", "3", "2", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "2", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "2", "2", "4", "2", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "4", "1", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "3", "3", 
"2", "2", "2", "3", "4", "3", "3", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "4", 
"2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", "1", "4", "4", "4", 
"3", "1", "1", "3", "3", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", 
"4", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "4", "2", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "4", "2", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "4", "3", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "1", "1", 
"4", "3", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", 
"4", "2", "4", "3", "1", "3", "3", "2", "3", "1", "2", "4", "3", 
"2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", "1", "2", "3", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "2", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "4", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", 
"4", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "2", "4", "3", "3", 
"3", "1", "3", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "3", "3", "1", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "4", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "2", "4", "2", "2", "1", "3", 
"4", "4", "2", "2", "1", "2", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "4", 
"4", "3", "3", "4", "4", "2", "1", "3", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", 
"3", "1", "2", "2", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", 
"2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "2", 
"2", "3", "3", "3", "1", "4", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "2", "4", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"1", "4", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "1", "3", "2", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "4", "4", "3", "3", "4", "4", "3", 
"2", "3", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", 
"3", "2", "4", "4", "1", "3", "3", "2", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "3", "4", "4", "2", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "4", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "1", "2", "1", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "3", "3", "2", "3", 
"4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "2", "1", "4", "3", "3", 
"3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "3", 
"2", "2", "2", "1", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "3", 
"3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "1", "1", "3", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "4", "3", "2", "2", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", "3", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "2", "1", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", 
"2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "2", "1", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "2", "3", "3", "4", "3", "3", "2", 
"3", "3", "4", "4", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "2", "4", "3", 
"3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "1", "2", "4", "3", 
"3", "3", "1", "1", "3", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "4", "2", "2", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "4", "2", "2", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", 
"2", "3", "2", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", "3", "2", "4", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "4", "4", "3", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", 
"2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "1", 
"3", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "1", "2", 
"1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "2", "2", "2", "3", "1", "3", "2", "2", 
"4", "4", "1", "3", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"4", "1", "2", "2", "1", "4", "4", "4", "2", "1", "3", "3", "1", 
"3", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", 
"3", "3", "1", "3", "2", "2", "4", "3", "1", "2", "3", "3", "3", 
"2", "3", "1", "4", "4", "2", "3", "3", "2", "4", "3", "2", "2", 
"3", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "2", "2", "1", 
"2", "1", "2", "4", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "1", 
"3", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "3", "2", "2", "4", "1", 
"1", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "2", "2", "3", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "1", "2", "1", "1", "3", "2", "2", "1", 
"2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", 
"2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "4", "1", 
"3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "2", "2", "4", "1", "2", "3", "3", "3", "2", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "3", "3", "2", "2", "4", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "1", 
"3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"2", "2", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "4", 
"3", "3", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "1", "1", 
"1", "4", "2", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "2", 
"2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "4", 
"2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "3", "3", "2", "2", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"3", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"4", "4", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "3", "1", 
"1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "3", "2", "4", "3", "2", "2", "3", "1", "3", "3", "1", "4", 
"4", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "1", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", 
"4", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", "2", "3", 
"1", "2", "2", "4", "1", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", 
"1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "4", "4", "3", "2", "1", "1", "4", 
"4", "4", "1", "3", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "4", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "1", "4", "4", "2", "2", "3", 
"3", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "3", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "2", "1", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "1", "1", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "4", "1", "1", "2", "4", "4", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "3", 
"1", "1", "4", "1", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", 
"2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "1", "4", "2", "2", "2", "4", "3", "3", 
"4", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "3", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", 
"1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", 
"1", "2", "4", "4", "2", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "4", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", 
"2", "3", "2", "3", "1", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "4", "2", "2", "1", "2", "4", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "3", "2", "1", "1", "3", 
"3", "4", "4", "4"), nr_trips = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
6L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
4L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 
4L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 
2L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 
3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
7L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 
2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
5L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 
0L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 
1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
0L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L)), row.names = c(NA, 3000L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: you can set the `coef` value, i.e. the length of the whiskers. As default it's a multiple of the interquartile range (IQR), set to `1.5`. Try `ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy)) + geom_boxplot(coef = 3.5)` to play around with  `coef` value. Seee [man page](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_boxplot.html) for more. Also, _minimal reproducible_ is preferred. You could also plot a distribution of your variable to get a sense of it.

Comment: @EricFail Thank you for the input. This would not really solve the problem though I believe. My issue is, that the outliers appear too early and not that the whiskers are too long. And I'm sorry, was the data output not sufficient as a minimal reproducible? If not, id be happy to update my question:)

Comment: Hi Yves. I've run your code on the sample data you provided and it does not reproduce the error you describe. None of the outliers are overlaid on the whiskers

Comment: @AllanCameron, Oh I'm sorry. there is a character limitation and I assume I have not given enough rows to trigger this issue. Thank you for looking into it though. I'll see if i can give better data to try

Comment: Ok, I've just tried it myself with the 3000 rows, and I do get this error. So I don't think its a lack of data points.

Comment: I didn't have any problem reproducing the issue. Other than the fact that there's so much data that it slows down my browser, I think this is a great reproducible example.

Comment: In addition to what others are saying I would reiterate my point about the distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting this behavior is because the whisker extends beyond `median + 1.5 * IQR`. From `help("geom_boxplot")`:

> The lower and upper hinges correspond to the first and third quartiles (the 25th and 75th percentiles). This differs slightly from the method used by the boxplot() function...
>
> The upper whisker extends from the hinge to the largest value no further than 1.5 * IQR from the hinge (where IQR is the inter-quartile range, or distance between the first and third quartiles).

A slight change to your `mutate` call will fix this issue:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(income_class) %>% 
  mutate(outlier = nr_trips > quantile(nr_trips,0.75) + IQR(nr_trips) * 1.5) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=income_class, y=nr_trips)) + 
  geom_boxplot(varwidth = TRUE, outlier.shape = NA)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=my_xlab)+
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", 
               aes(shape="mean"), 
               size=4,
               colour = "red",
               geom="point") +
  scale_shape_manual("", values=c("mean"="x"))+
  theme_minimal() + 
  geom_jitter(data = function(x) dplyr::filter_(x, ~ outlier), width = 0.25, height = 0, alpha = .1, aes(color = "outlier")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("outlier" = "black"))+
  labs(x = "Income class", y="Number of AToD trips")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,2,4,6,8, 10, 12, 14), limits = c(0, 12))
```

[image]